# How to get framebuffer in Unreal Engine 4?

Tags: unreal-engine4, vulkan

I'm using Unreal as a server for simulation. Now I can connect to this from Python client and transmit/receive data via UDP. But I still haven't found a proper way to capture frames and stream it to Python client to process in OpenCV.

I tried to make screenshots and save it to file, but this way is too slow.

I also tried to render to texture target, but it also is not optimal way for me, because I need render 2 times (both for camera and 2d capturer).

Now I'm find a way to access a Vulkan framebuffer (I'm on Linux), but I can't find any docs or examples, how to do it.

How to get raw framebuffer byte array in custom c++ actor?

Comment: What makes you think there is a "raw framebuffer byte array" somewhere? Vulkan certainly defines no such thing. Is the UE4-engine based application even running in your current process?

Comment: @NicolBolas, because it (framebuffer) must be somewhere, how else? Besides, I found this [template](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/VulkanRHI/FTransitionAndLayoutManagerData/FFramebufferList/Framebuffer/index.html)

Comment: "Is the UE4-engine based application even running in your current process?" - Emm, yes, it is

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hello you can actually access this information from a delegate: FSlateApplication::Get().GetRenderer()->OnBackBufferReadyToPresent() this will be call when the frame is ready and it will return a pointer of the SWindow rendered and a FTexture2DRHIRef containing the actual backbuffer, having the RHI texture is your opportunity to captures the bytes.

UE has a class already that is doing what you want inside their implementation for the virtual camera they use with iPad. It is called FFrameGrabber, you can use that one or if you need something more sophisticated you can see how the implemented the OnBackBufferReadyToPresent delegate

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for are called render targets and scene captures in unreal engine.

Can't give you an exact code how to export these information out from ue4 into your python application as i don't have much idea what is that you need exactly but maybe a good start would be searching the engine code.

Tutorial Setting up render targets
https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/Rendering/RenderTargets/index.html

I am pretty sure you're able to query the framebuffer/ render target textures from the gpu and read them in c++. And then pass it over to your application.

Also accessing the gpu resources directly between processes are not supported in unreal engine. I understand using render targets are too slow, maybe have a look at the twitch stream plugin in UE4 to find out their fast solution for streaming.